# AS3 stopping a timer from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, class, timer

Hi I'm trying to stop a timer in stopwatch class from MainMenu class. But my code doesn't work, here is my code:

in MainMenu class i've method:

```
public function pauseGame (e:MouseEvent){
    timestop = new Stopwatch();
    timestop.Stoptimer();
    }
```

in class Stopwatch i try to stop my timer with:

```
 public function Stoptimer(){
    timer.stop();
        timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeFun);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You should debug the code to see what is failing, if you're not getting an error then put trace("got here"); statements throughout the code to determine which parts worked http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_as3_debugging.html.

Comment: in func Stoptimer() I've try to put trace, the trace is work fine but the timer still don't stop?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer below is correct.  The problem isn't that you're not creating a Stopwatch correctly or that you're not calling the right method.  The problem is you're creating a new Stopwatch and stopping it instead of stopping some existing Stopwatch that was created earlier.  The timestop = new Stopwatch(); should go in the constructor or some other method that is called before the game starts.

Answer (score 1):

without seeing more code I can only guess, but I think the issue is that you are creating a new stopwatch when you are pausing the game

```
public function pauseGame (e:MouseEvent){
    timestop = new Stopwatch();  // <-- a new instance with a new timer inside
    timestop.Stoptimer();
}
```

the timestop should be a global variable so you shouldn't need to instantiate it again, so this should be enough:

```
public function pauseGame (e:MouseEvent){
    timestop.Stoptimer();
}
```

Comment: Hi i'm newbie in as3, wolud you mind to give me sample code of stopping a timer from another class...

Comment: probably not the best advice, but try defining `timer` in stopwatch as a public(or private) static var. as long as you don't have multiple stopwatches starting and stopping it might just work.